# How to change the startup activity in android

Tags: android, authentication, android-manifest, homescreen, app-startup

For the first time use of the application I will show the user with a login screen which i will defined in manifest file as "android.intent.action.MAIN". After a successful login, each time application starts I want the user to see the home screen. Please let me know how i can achieve this.

Also please let me know is there any way I can change the MAIN activity programmatically after a successful login, So that I can redirect to the home screen.

Thanks,

Vijay

Comment: After Successful login you can store your data in SharedPreferences and when again application start check the SharedPreferences. If there is value then start other activity else login setContentView.

Comment: I think this link will help you.... [link](http://blog.donnfelker.com/2011/02/17/android-a-simple-eula-for-your-android-apps/) Thanks....

Comment: @casperOne Why this question has been closed?

Comment: "Gimme teh codez" questions are usually closed as NARQ

Comment: @casperOne I don't think that's the case here... Although, anyway, the question has been answered and in various ways, so that's not a problem.

Comment: I dont know whats wrong with the question. But anyways you guys have saved my time & thanks for all the answers.
Thanks Alex for the solution. It worked!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you subclass `Application` class and call the activity you need from your Application's `onCreate()` ? And in the manifest you remove that `intent.MAIN`.

Comment: Thanks for that. will implement it.

Comment: I have subclassed the Application & added it under the application tag in manifest. As suggested I removed the Intent-Filter for the Login Activity. Now the Manifest file does not contain Intent.Main anymore. Application is successfully installed, but it is not showing in the  list.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can set the main activity programmatically, but you can set a boolean in your `sharedPreferences`. If this boolean is `true`, then you call your `HomeActivity`, and finish your `LoginActivity`.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I would, from the login screen simply call the home screen. Or from the home screen, if the login details are not saved/ valid, then show the login screen.

Basically, it is not necessary or a good programming practice to do what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

When you have successfully logged in, call `finish();` in the main activity which will remove it from the stack. Then in your HomeScreenActivity, override the back button to act as the home button:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```